# Multiplying matrices c++

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra

I want to make a program capable of rising the 2x2 matrix to k power. I know how to make one that is going to square it but once i want to reach higher powers i struggle to save the results I have and use it in the next equation. a,b,c,d are the numbers in the matrix, n is the amount of matrix I will want to do in one time, k is the power i want the matrix to be taken to and m is modulo which I want to use on the numbers. I know there is a method of making this fairly simply but I am unable to figure out a good way to use my results from the equation done before in the next equation.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int mnoz(int a, int b, int c,int d,int m){

    int a2 = (a*a + c*b) % m;

    int b2 = (a*b + b*d) % m;

    int c2 = (c*a + d*c) % m;

    int d2 = (c*b + d*d) % m;
    return a2, b2, c2, d2;
}

int main()

{

    int a, b, c, d, k, m, n;

    int e, f, g, h;

    int e2, f2, g2, h2;

    cin >> n;



    // a^k = (a^2)^k/2

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){

        cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> k >> m;

        if (k == 1){

            cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << d << endl;



        }



        else if (k == 2){

            e = (a*a + c*b) % m;

            f = (a*b + b*d) % m;

            g = (c*a + d*c) % m;

            h = (c*b + d*d) % m;

            cout << e << " " << f << " " << g << " " << h << endl;

        }
        else{

            if (k % 2 == 0){
                e = (a*a + c*b) % m;

                f = (a*b + b*d) % m;

                g = (c*a + d*c) % m;

                h = (c*b + d*d) % m;
                int z = (k/2)-1;

                for (int j = 0; j < z; j++){
                    int e2 = e;
                    int f2 = f;
                    int g2 = g;
                    int h2 = h;
                    mnoz(e2, f2, g2, h2, m);

                }
                cout << e << " " << f << " " << g << " " << h << endl;

            }
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I believe you'll need to learn the memory management side of C or C++ - allocate the 2x2 matrix as a double pointer or vector of vectors. Then you'll be able to pass it to the function and keep the partial products as you go.

Answer (score 2):

To minimize the number of multiplications, you can use a recursive method.

To give an analogy with real numbers, say you want to compute `a^n`.

1. Check whether n is even or odd.
2. If even, compute `b = a^(n/2)`. Then the final result is `b*b`.
3. If odd, compute `b = a^((n-1)/2`. Then the final result is `b*b*a`.

Since you are talking matrices instead of numbers, you need to be able multiply any two matrices. You can create a class/struct for the matrix and add an `operator*()` function.

Here's some sample code.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Matrix
{
   Matrix(double pa, double pb, double pc, double pd) : a(pa), b(pb), c(pc), d(pd) {}

   Matrix operator*(Matrix const& rhs) const
   {
      double an = this->a*rhs.a + this->b*rhs.c;
      double bn = this->a*rhs.b + this->b*rhs.d;
      double cn = this->c*rhs.a + this->d*rhs.c;
      double dn = this->c*rhs.b + this->d*rhs.d;
      return Matrix(an, bn, cn, dn);
   }

   Matrix square() const
   {
      return (*this)*(*this);
   }

   double a;
   double b;
   double c;
   double d;
};

Matrix matrixPower(Matrix const& m, int k)
{
   if ( k == 1 )
   {
      return m;
   }

   Matrix out = matrixPower(m, k/2).square();
   if ( k%2 == 1 )
   {
      return out*m;
   }
   else
   {
      return out;
   }
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Matrix const& m)
{
   out << "[ " << m.a << " " << m.b << " ]\n";
   out << "[ " << m.c << " " << m.d << " ]\n";
}

int main()
{
   Matrix m(0.4, 0.7, 0.7, 0.4);
   std::cout << matrixPower(m, 5) << std::endl;
   std::cout << matrixPower(m, 10) << std::endl;
   std::cout << matrixPower(m, 15) << std::endl;
};
```

The output:

```
[ 0.80404 0.80647 ]
[ 0.80647 0.80404 ]

[ 1.29687 1.29687 ]
[ 1.29687 1.29687 ]

[ 2.08862 2.08862 ]
[ 2.08862 2.08862 ]
```